# Ubuntu 21.04 Simplescan error "The folder contents cannot be displayed. Operation not supported."

Tags: upgrade

Since upgrading to 21.04 Simplescan scans the document but when I try to save it I get the message "The folder contents could not be displayed. Operation not supported." It worked OK in 20.04.

Comment: Try saving it in a different folder.

Answer (score 1):

Saving in a different folder works.

Comment: Hi there, I see contrary to the other commenter that there is no answer here to accept since the answer was offered in a comment. I'll make an edit to this answer to present it as an independent answer instead of as a "thank you" like it is now. If you could please accept you answer once you're allowed to, it'll make it obvious to others that this works. Thanks.